# Why do we pronounce "disease" like that?

Tags: nouns, pronunciation, vowels

What is the rule of pronunciation in this case? Why do we say like if there was an "e" in place of the "i"?

Comment: "e" instead of "i"? How do you think we pronounce it? I've only heard it as pronounced [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/disease) (`dih-zeez`)

Comment: English vowels in unstressed syllables (like the first syllable of *disease*) can have substantial variation depending on the dialect. Native English speakers generally don't hear this variation. I think most English speakers use either a schwa /ə/ or a short i /ɪ/. Is this difference what you're asking about?

Comment: @PeterShor - Yep thanks for clarifying, I didn't really now how to ask it correctly...

Answer (score 1):

That's not how I pronounce it, and that's not the pronunciation recorded in my dictionary.

Which accent / dialect do you speak?  It may be that the pronunciation in your speech community differs from the "standard" pronunciation in a systematic way, and that your observation about *disease* is an instance of this deviation.